# TeX Live 2023 Unknown Publisher

Tags: texlive, installing, iso

I downloaded the ISO of TeX Live 2023. When opening the file, the following warning comes out:

[image]

I’m working on Windows 11. Should I proceed anyway regardless of the warning?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 and get the same message for TeXLive 21, 22 and 23. The installer is fine as long as you got it from the tug.org website, not sure about other sites, I had no issues so go ahead with the installation. Think it is not registered with Microsoft or something along those lines

Comment: Thanks @JamesT for confirming the error! Does anyone know for sure why this happens?

Comment: It is not an error, it is Microsoft telling you that publisher is unknown and to confirm you want to proceed. There is nothing wrong with that message at all, your installation will be fine

Comment: You can verify the hash to ensure file integrity.

Comment: Yes, that is not an error, but I think it would be more convenient for the TeX Live authors to register it with Microsoft. So the end user does not have to worry and feels the installation is “safer”.

Comment: I do not care to spend my time registering anything with Microsoft, Apple, Google, or any other supposed authority. If someone else wants to do so, fine with me.